# Reactive Extensions wait for method to finish

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive

We are starting to refactor our silverlight application using some reactive extensions. I have an Initialize method that does some work. I have a call to a method within the Initialize method that must be completed before the rest of the Initialize method is called.

```
 LoadTaskQueues(_currentUser.InstitutionID);

        if (_params.Task != null)
        {
            LoadTaskInformation(_params.Task);
            return null;
        }
```

I need to have LoadTaskQueues completed before it runs the LoadTaskInformation.

Comment: Can you include the method signatures for `LoadTaskQueues` and `LoadTaskInformation`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that LoadTaskQueues returns IObservable (you don't specify), you want to Subscribe here:

```
LoadTaskQueues()
    .Where(_ => _params.Task != null)
    .Subscribe(_ =>  LoadTaskInformation(_params.Task));
```